# Character collision detection on 2D array tileset based map

Tags: collision-detection, javascript, html-canvas, tilesets

I have a very basic collision detection working, but not quite there yet. Now as I understand I'm only checking against the left top corner of the character for collision detection. And it only works if I move character to the left. If I move to the right, the collision is not being detected. How can I check for all the sides of the character for collision and not only left top? Let's say my character sprite size is 36px.

```
var mapArray = [
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
];

function isPositionWall(ptX, ptY) {
  var gridX = Math.floor(ptX / 36);
  var gridY = Math.floor(ptY / 36);
  if(mapArray[gridY][gridX] != 0) {
    return true;
  }
}

if(isPositionWall(boatPosX, boatPosY)) {
    boatPosX = oldPosY;
    console.log("collision");
  }
```

Comment: Why are you setting `boatPosX` to the previous __vertical__ position? Is the statement incomplete, or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: there is an excellent tutorial for collision detection in a tile based game from the creator of the game "N" found [here](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) in case your collision demands rise over time in complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way possible to perform a collision detection is checking the next position an object should move to: if there is a free place, move it, if there is a wall, don't move it, etc.
Simple implementation:

```
// get tile at position
function getTileAt(x, y) {
    var gridX = Math.floor(x / 36);
    var gridY = Math.floor(y / 36);
    return mapArray[gridY][gridX];
}

// check if the place we want to move an object to is free
function isTileFree(x, y) {
    return getTileAt(x, y) == 0;
}

// x, y are relative coordinates
function move(x, y) {
    if (isTileFree(boatPosX + x, boatPosY + y)
    {
        boatPosX += x;
        boatPosY += y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you give me an example with real numbers? Because you say check the place we want to move to and it takes x, y. What those x, y are supposed to be? Why not just check against right upcoming array like so mapArray[gridY][gridX + 1]?

Comment: The idea seems to be that the `move`-function receives the direction in form of the x- and y-difference between the old and the new position. Providing these values would be the responsibility of the calling code. And by the way: I also think the function shouldn't be called `move` but rather `tryMove` and return true or false depending on whether it worked or not.